# With the Tkinter library in python, on a canvas how do I rotate a rectangle?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am looking to switch a rectangle from horizontal to vertical. It is a rectangle on a canvas. With the Tkinter library in python, on a canvas how do I rotate a rectangle?

Comment: I have tried using winfo_x() and winfo_y() to fetch the x and y coordinates and then leave the top left as there inital coordinates and then adding the width in the y of the second y coordinate

Comment: newxone = canvas.winfo_x(rec)newyone = canvas.winfo_y(rec)
            newxtwo = newxone + 25
            newytwo = newyone + 56
            rec = canvas.create_rectangle(newxone, newyone, newxtwo, newytwo)

Comment: `newxone = canvas.winfo_x(rec)`
            `newyone = canvas.winfo_y(rec)`
            `newxtwo = newxone + 25`
            `newytwo = newyone + 56`
            `rec = canvas.create_rectangle(newxone, newyone, newxtwo, newytwo)`

Comment: Try searching for equations to rotate a rectangle. It's just a little math, and then you can use the `coords` method to adjust the coordinates on the canvas.

Comment: Okay thanks so much!